How to add 'unit price' tab in New Order Email template.. I'm using 'Magento 2.4.6'
I want to add a 'unit price' tab and actual price of the products like this in New Order Email template.. I'm using 'Magento 2.4.6'
enter image description here
I need a proper code that i can implement in files with the help of file path as well, Thank You

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

we can add column into order email template by following way
1.app/design/frontend/[themeparent]/[themename]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate
// phpcs:disable Magento2.Files.LineLength, Generic.Files.LineLength

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */

/** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper */
$_item = $block->getItem();
$_order = $_item->getOrder();
?>
<tr>
    <td class="item-info<?= ($block->getItemOptions() ? ' has-extra' : '') ?>">
        <p class="product-name"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
        <p class="sku"><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>: <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()) : ?>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option) : ?>
                    <dt><strong><em><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></em></strong></dt>
                    <dd>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ nl2br($option['value']) ?>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
        <?php if ($addInfoBlock) : ?>
            <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-unitprice">
        <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_item->getPrice()) ?>
    </td>
    <td class="item-qty"><?= (float) $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?></td>
    <td class="item-price">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getItemPrice($_item) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php if (
    $_item->getGiftMessageId()
    && $_giftMessage = $this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
    ->getGiftMessage($_item->getGiftMessageId())
) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="item-extra">
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Gift Message')) ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('From:')) ?></strong> <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('To:')) ?></strong> <?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Message:')) ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $escaper->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>


app/design/frontend/[themeparent]/[themename]/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items.phtml
 <?php
 /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

 /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items */
 ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_order) : ?>
 <?php $_items = $_order->getAllItems(); ?>
 <table class="email-items">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th class="item-info">
                 <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Items')) ?>
             </th>
             <th class="item-unitprice">
                 <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Unit Price')) ?>
             </th>
             <th class="item-qty">
                 <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
             </th>
             <th class="item-price">
                 <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>
             </th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <?php foreach ($_items as $_item) : ?>
         <?php if (!$_item->getParentItem()) : ?>
             <tbody>
                 <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
             </tbody>
         <?php endif; ?>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     <tfoot class="order-totals">
         <?= $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>
     </tfoot>
 </table>
 <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
         ->isMessagesAllowed('order', $_order, $_order->getStore())
     && $_order->getGiftMessageId()
 ) : ?>
     <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper(\Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message::class)
         ->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
     <?php if ($_giftMessage) : ?>
         <br />
         <table class="message-gift">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <h3><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Gift Message for this Order')) ?></h3>
                     <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('From:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                     <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('To:')) ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                     <br /><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Message:')) ?></strong>
                     <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     <?php endif; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>




ok but i post 1 more question about quantity increment & decrement in Magento 2.4.6 kindly review that question as well..
